# PNP S9012H switching low current

Tags: transistors, batteries, pnp

[image: drawn attempt]

**EDIT**: I have added the drawn circuit. The LED ([here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Intensity-Components-Lighting-Floodlight-Spotlight/dp/B07BVK3Z6W)) is 1W @ 3.4V so pulls about 300mA. I was hoping I could get somewhere close to that.
Thanks.

I am following an online course and struggling to get my head around transistors. Just when I think I have it something like this confuses me!
The PNP in my circuit is only allowing around 40mA to the LED and I am unsure why. The image shows the 4.2v battery connected to a TP4056 charging IC. One side is connected to a 6V solar panel and the other side is a 3V LED.

The idea is that when there is no light on the solar panel the PNP is closed, allowing the current from the battery to the LED. When there is light on solar panel the base current forces the PNP to open, cutting the power to the LED. Hopefully I have this part correct.

The problem is, like I say, that the LED is not too bright and when I put it through the meter I get ~40mA. Is there anyway to allow more current flow through this transistor or do I need different parts. The LED directly to the battery hits over 200mA.

Also, sorry about the photo instead of the circuit diagram, I can't figure out how to add ICs to them which would have made it very confusing.

[image: PNP S9012H and TP4056]

Comment: Could you take the time to draw a schematic so we don't have to reverse engineer your picture. Hand drawn if need be.

Comment: Add link to LED, it probably can’t handle more than 50 mA. You certainly can’t put 3.7V across it. Looks like R=201 or 200 ohms. And you want Ic/Ib=20 max.

Comment: I have 5mm LEDs that are blinding at 20mA in 30 deg . SMT LEDs are 160 deg so intensity is much less. My guess is those LEDs do not serve your purpose, so don’t use them. 20mA max.

Comment: I've edited the original post. The LED is a bright SMD, 1W. I would like to get about 150mA through it but can't get above 40mA with the current setup.

Comment: The arrowhead in the transistor symbol goes on the emitter, not on the collector, and normally points toward the negative supply.

Comment: After seeing the schematic: This is less trivial then you seem to think. You probably want hysteresis for starters to prevent the LED from flickering when the light level is just at the threshold region. You probably also want something to tune the light level at which switchover happens.